# Angular 16: SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported

Tags: angular, angular16

I have updated my Angular app to version 16 and now in older browsers I am getting the error which says *"SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported."*

I am trying to use polyfills to support modern browser features in the older browsers.

Here is the `polyfills.ts` file:

```
import 'core-js';
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

import 'zone.js';
```

This is the tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015"
  },
```

This is the error on Firefox (v75):

[image]

Comment: Angular [browser support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) isn't going to cover a [browser version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/75.0/releasenotes/) from over three years ago. You can't polyfill syntax, only APIs (new methods, etc.).

Comment: Firefox 75 has a usage of 0%. Why would you want to support this version today? https://caniuse.com/usage-table

Comment: @JSONDerulo 
Got it, I have added support for Firefox (>= v90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support older browser, you need to create/update your`.browserslistrc` to include the browsers you want to support !

By [default Angular uses](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support):

```
last 2 Chrome versions
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added this configuration

Chrome >=99
Firefox >=99
Edge >=79
Safari >=13
iOS >=13

and worked in the older browsers.

Comment: @AbhinavAkhil can you accept the answer ? :)